# Rounded corners not rendering correctly on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Does anyone know why the rounded corners look wrong?

```
ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + this.cornerRadius, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + thisWidth - this.cornerRadius, y);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + thisWidth, y, x + thisWidth, y + this.cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(x + thisWidth, y + thisHeight - this.cornerRadius);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + thisWidth, y + thisHeight, x + thisWidth - this.cornerRadius, y + thisHeight, this.cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(x + this.cornerRadius, y + thisHeight);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + thisHeight, x, y + this.height - this.cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + this.cornerRadius);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + this.cornerRadius, y);
  ctx.closePath();
```

[image: Issue with rounded corners]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using quadratic curves rather than arcs?

Comment: No, that's just how I went about it.

Comment: I updated to use arc and it's the same result.

Comment: Could you give us more of the code? It's a little hard to follow not knowing what this.cornerRadius and thisWidth are. Just share a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo or something

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was implied. I'm drawing the rectangle in the image. So thisWidth and thisHeight are the dimensions of the rectangle and cornerRadius is the radius of the corners.

Comment: It kind of is, but a demo would make it clearer. You're sure you're using this.cornerRadius correctly, right? Some places you use this.height and others you use thisHeight.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going wrong for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas = document.getElementById('a');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function roundedRect(x,y,w,h,radius){
    ctx.moveTo(x+radius,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+w-radius,y);
    ctx.arcTo(x+w,y,x+w,y+radius,radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x+w,y+h-radius);
    ctx.arcTo(x+w,y+h,x+w-radius,y+h,radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x+radius,y+h);
    ctx.arcTo(x,y+h,x,y+h-radius,radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y+radius);
    ctx.arcTo(x,y,x+radius,y,radius);    
    ctx.stroke();
}
roundedRect(100,50,100,100,10);
```

The arcTo method was created for these kinds of purposes. Read about the arcTo method [here](http://www.scriptol.com/html5/canvas/arcto.php). (MDN doesn't have very good documentation or examples on it)
[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/sGL5h/)

Comment: I went to using your snippet in my code and it renders the same. I think there is another issue going on. You actually want to put in a .5 for the x and y or you get fuzzy lines. (http://jsfiddle.net/ischyrus/5GpMv/) If you look at that the corners still don't look right.

Comment: @Steven, I think it's an OS or browser specific issue then because the corners look perfectly fine to me. The 0.5 pixels are used commonly ([explained here](http://www.diveintohtml5.com/canvas.html#pixel-madness)).